# объект ошибка типа builtin не subsettable

Tags: r

Только начал осваивать язык программирования R. Надо было найти все NA в таблице.  Сначала это получилось, но на следующие попытки выдавал ошибку. Видел несколько похожих случаев, но не понял как применить на мой. Буду рад любой попытке, заранее спасибо.
Мой код:

```
NAF <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/User/Documents/NAF.csv", header = TRUE)
NAF$carbon[NAF$carbon == 000000e+00] <- NA
is.na[NAF]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По большому счёту вам достаточно функций `is.na()` и `which()`.

`is.na()` - проверка является ли значение NA;
`which()` - возвращает индексы элементов вектора (столбца таблицы в вашем случае) которые соответствуют заданному выражению.

```r
# тестовая таблица
NAF <- data.frame( a = c(1,2,NA,4,NA),
                   b = c("k","o","c",NA,"r"),
                   c = c("P",NA,NA,"Q",NA))

# найти NA в столбце
NAF$a[ is.na(NAF$a) ]
#> [1] NA NA

# найти номера строк в столбце со значением NA
which( is.na(NAF$c) )
#> [1] 2 3 5

# найти все NA в таблице
sapply(NAF, function(x) x[ is.na(x) ] )
#> $a
#> [1] NA NA
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] <NA>
#> Levels: c k o r
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> Levels: P Q

# получить индексы всех NA в таблице
sapply(NAF, function(x) which( is.na(x) ) )
#> $a
#> [1] 3 5
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 2 3 5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>